# D3Js updating wrong elements using call

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3JS and you can find the code at http://jsfiddle.net/3n8wD/

I am a facing an issue and any pointers would help

When I move the line it separates as expected, but as soon as I try to move the circles away it jumps back to the line.

On inspecting the Array, looks like the circle array is updating as I am moving the link, not sure what is causing that.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated. below is the code that i have on jsfiddle

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;
graph1 = {"nodes":[{"x":444,"y":275},{"x":378,"y":324}],"links":[{"source":1,"target":0}]}


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
var onDraggable = function(d1) {
          console.log(d1);

          d1.x = d3.event.x, d1.y = d3.event.y;
          d3.select(this).attr("cx", d1.x).attr("cy", d1.y);
          //console.log(d1);
          link.filter(function(l) { return l.source === d1; }).attr("x1", d3.event.x).attr("y1", d3.event.y);
          link.filter(function(l) { return l.target === d1; }).attr("x2", d3.event.x).attr("y2", d3.event.y);


        }
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
      .origin(function(d) { return d; })
      .on("drag", onDraggable)




  var onDraggable1 = function(d) {
          //d.x1 = d3.event.x1, d.y1 = d3.event.y1, d.x2=d3.event.x2, y2=d3.event.y2;
          var mouseX = d3.mouse(this)[0];
          var mouseY = d3.mouse(this)[1];
          var relativeX = mouseX-d.source.x;
          var relativeY = mouseY-d.source.y;
          console.log(d);

          //console.log(d);
         // d3.select(this).attr("x1", d3.event.x).attr("y1", d3.event.y).attr("x2", d3.event.x).attr("y2", d3.event.y);
          d.source.x= d.source.x+relativeX;
          d.source.y = d.source.y+relativeY;
          d.target.x= d.target.x+relativeX;
          d.target.y = d.target.y+relativeY;

          d3.select(this).attr("x1", d.source.x).attr("y1", d.source.y);
          d3.select(this).attr("x2", d.target.x).attr("y2", d.target.y);

        }
var drag1 = d3.behavior.drag()
      .origin(function(d) { return d; })
      .on("drag", onDraggable1);

  graph1.links.forEach(function(d) {
    d.source = graph1.nodes[d.source];
    d.target = graph1.nodes[d.target];
  });




var node = svg.append("g").attr("class","node")
    .selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph1.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .call(drag);

var link = svg.append("g").attr("class","link")
    .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph1.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .call(drag1);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you *want* the behaviour to be?  Do you want the lines and circles to move together, or do you want them to be completely independent?

Comment: When one clicks on the circle and drag the line would expand, but at the same time when one clicks on the line and drags it should move. Both these are working. The issue is after the line is separated from the circles and when one try to move the circles away it won't, it will go back and connect to the line.

Comment: So when you move the line, it *is* supposed to separate from the node (and stay separated, so that it is no longer attached to that node)?  The other possibility was that you wanted to move the line and nodes together, as opposed to stretching/twisting it like when you move a node.

Comment: correct the idea is to separate the nodes and line, and be able to move the nodes independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your nodes are "jumping" to the end of the line, even after the line has been moved away, is because the data object for the node is ***the same*** object as the source/target data object for the line.  The `d` value for the node and the `d.source` or `d.target` value for the link are just pointers (references) to the same object in the browser's memory.  Everything you do to that data object is reflected in both the link and the node.  That's what makes the node-drag function work: you change the data object directly, and then you update the position of the line and the circle to match their already-changed data value.

So, even though you don't update the circle's `cx` and `cy` position at the time you move the line, the statements `d.source.x =` etc. in the line drag method are setting the `d.x` and `d.y` values for the nodes.  Then in the node drag method, when you access these values to determine the new position, the movement is determined relative to the end of the line, not to the position of the circle on screen.

So how do you get the behaviour you want, to separate the line from the node?  You need to create a *new* data object for the line's source and target when you start to drag it, one that no longer references the nodes' data objects.  You only need to do this once, at the start of the drag, so you use the [`dragstart` event](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#wiki-on) of the drag behaviour object:

```
var drag1 = d3.behavior.drag()
      .origin(function(d) { return d; })
      .on("dragstart", separateNodes);
      .on("drag", onDraggable1);
```

The `separateNodes` method is going to be quite short.  All we have to do is, for both the target and the source of the link, create a new data object that is a copy of the existing target/source object (but which can be edited independently of the original object).  Javascript doesn't have any default methods for copying an object (although [various extensions do](http://heyjavascript.com/4-creative-ways-to-clone-objects/)), but if the object in question just consists of x and y attributes, it is easy to do.

```
var separateNodes = function(d) {
    //create new data objects that are copies of d.source and d.target
    var newSource = {x:d.source.x, y:d.source.y};
    var newTarget = {x:d.target.x, y:d.target.y};

    //set the new objects as the target/source of this link
    d.source = newSource; 
    d.target = newTarget;
}
```

You could even skip the variable declarations and just merge it all into one line for source and one for target, but I find it easier to understand like this.  I should mention, however, that this approach works because x and y are both just simple data types (numbers), not pointers to objects.  So when it says `x:d.source.x`, you are actually getting a new copy of that number which you can change without having it affect the original object that contained that number.

If, however, your nodes and links also have a `value` property that is a complex data object, then you have to decide what you want to do when the line separates from the node: do you want to create a copy of the entire value data object, or maintain the link to the original object, or replace it with a null (empty/undefined) object?  The first case is complicated, and depends on the data structure of the value object; for the second you don't need to do anything (except remember that you've got multiple pointers to the same object); and for the last case you just add a `value:null,` attribute to the `newSource` and `newTarget` object definitions in your `separateNodes` function.

Hope that all makes sense,
--ABR

Comment: Thanks that accomplishes what I want. Some follow-up question as I am new to D3JS, how did you figure out they are referring to the same object in browser ? are there any tools are debug methods one could deploy to figure out these ?

Comment: one more question, if I want to attach the nodes back to line so when I drag the nodes the line expands…something similar to what we started with initially. What is the best method to accomplish that ?

Comment: or in other words how could I re associate them to the same object at certain conditions ?

Comment: How did I figure it out?  I looked at the code for the other drag methods to see how they worked. *BUT* this is a standard feature (if one that is easy to forget) -- all variables that reference objects and arrays are just pointers.

Comment: is this the line that is joining the pointers together ?d.source = graph1.nodes[d.source];
    d.target = graph1.nodes[d.target];

Comment: Yes.  In the original data structure, the source and target of the link are just index numbers; that line replaces the index number with the node (data object) at that index.

Comment: On your question about how to re-connect lines with nodes, in part that is simple and in part quite complex.  The easy part is, once you have a node selected and a link selected that you want to join up, just set the link's `d.source` or `d.target` property to the node's data object again.  The tricky part will be figuring out the code for how to have the user select a node and a link and indicate they want them joined.

Comment: On debugging:  use the === operator to test if two variables reference the exact same object or array.  For example, copy this code into your console: `var d1 = {x:302}, d2 = {x:302}, d3 = d1;  console.log("d1 === d2: " + (d1 === d2)); console.log("d1 === d3: " + (d1 === d3));` you should get "false" for the first comparison but "true" for the second.