# SVG element moves (jumps) after drag operation and then pan operation

Tags: d3.js

While trying to implement a moveable line segment in a d3 chart, I came across a behavior that I thought was strange. The endpoints of the line segment can be moved around and placed anywhere. This is done via a drag behavior. The drag behavior simply updates the data underlying the line segment (path). If the user then tries to pan the chart area with the line segment after the line data has changed via the drag operation, the line segment jumps as soon as the pan operation starts.

```
line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate('linear')
       .x(function(d) { return x(d.index); })
       .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });
```

I did notice that the y axis domain changes as soon as the drag operation starts. Once the drag operation is complete and the pan operation starts the y axis domain changes again. This explains the reason why the same input (d.index=40, d.value=100.3) to the y axis function returns different values for each of the operations: the y axis domain is different in each operation.

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: You may need to set [`drag.origin()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#wiki-origin). Without seeing your code, we can't really help you.

Comment: Most likely problem is that you are changing the attributes of the line, but not the underlying data objects (see a [similar problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20795399/3128209)).  When you zoom or pan, everything is redrawn based on their data values and so your lines "jump" back to their position.  But as @LarsKotthoff said, it's really just speculation without seeing more of your code.